# Get inserted key before commit session

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id'))

parent = Parent()
db.session.add(parent)

child = Child()
child.parent_id = parent.id
db.session.add(child)

db.session.commit()
```

I want to **INSERT** into both `parent` and `child` tables inside a session considering that the `parent_id` must be included in the `child` table. In the moment I create the `child` object, `parent.id` is **None**.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could use [flush()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html?highlight=flush#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush) to flush changes to the database and thus have  your primary-key field updated:

```
parent = Parent()
db.session.add(parent)
db.session.flush()

print parent.id  # after flush(), parent object would be automatically
                 # assigned with a unique primary key to its id field 

child = Child()
child.parent_id = parent.id
db.session.add(child)
```