# I can't save to SQLAlchemy when the foreignkey is included

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I can create my tables with SQL Alchemy. Here is my full code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, ForeignKey, 
String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True)

class Cars(Base):
    __tablename__ = "car"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    brand = Column(String)
    year = Column(Integer)
    plate = Column(String, unique=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))


engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:pass@localhost:5432/sqlalchemy')
#Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


user = User()
user.username = "Jack"

car = Cars()
car.brand = "Bmw"
car.plate = "NK 948"
car.year = 2016
car.owner_id = user

session.add(user)
session.add(car)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

But when I try to save it to database I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
.
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'User' [SQL: 'INSERT INTO car (brand, year, plate, owner_id) VALUES (%(brand)s, %(year)s, %(plate)s, %(owner_id)s) RETURNING car.id'] [parameters: {'brand': 'Bmw', 'year': 2016, 'plate': 'NK 948', 'owner_id': <__main__.User object at 0x10d27d358>}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems that I can save raws for the User table. But for the Cars tables, I think there is something wrong with the ForeignKey. But I didn't understand.

Thanks.

Comment: And I want to add one more thing. I tried to change the car.owner_id = user with car.owner_id = user.id, this time I don't get any error but the owner_id is Null in database in this case.

Comment: The first attempt fails because as the exception says, psycopg does not understand SQLA model objects, which you're assigning to the foreign key column (instead of a relationship attribute). The second failure resulting in NULL is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242523/get-inserted-key-before-commit-session

Comment: Thank you. So it seems that I always have to use flush() function each time adding something to database.

Comment: In a way if you need some generated values from the DB, though you can hide it using the ORM relationships. If `Cars` had  for example `owner = relationship("User")` and you'd assign `car.owner = user`, then SQLA would handle inserting the objects in a suitable order so that the foreign key can be filled for you.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I'm still trying to learn. relationship seems a little confusing to me for now. But I'll learn it too hopefully :) I can't find a great tutorial for SQLAlchemy. But I'm trying to test everything step by step.