# Foreign key column populating with NULL

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a foreign key `department_id` for employee. But the `department_id` column value is NULL not 1 as it should be.

Any advise/suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///db.sqlite3', echo=False)

Base = declarative_base()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    department_name = Column(String)

class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    employee_name = Column(String)
    department_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('department.id'))

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

d = Department(department_name='electronics')
session.add(d)

e = Employee(employee_name='alice')
session.add(e)

session.commit()
```

Output:

```
sqlite> select * from department;
1|electronics

sqlite> select * from employee;
1|alice|
```

Output should be:

```
sqlite> select * from department;
1|electronics

sqlite> select * from employee;
1|alice|1
```

Comment: Unless you left some code out, you never set `department_id` of `e`. If you did leave the assignment out, this will probably be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242523/get-inserted-key-before-commit-session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `department` to the `employee` object:

```
e = Employee(employee_name='alice', department = d)
```

Alternatively, you can introduce introduce a [many-to-many relationship](https://www.pythoncentral.io/sqlalchemy-orm-examples/) between `department` and `employee`

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, String, Integer, ForeignKey, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    employees = relationship(
        'Employee',
        secondary='department_employee_link'
    )

class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    hired_on = Column(
        DateTime,
        default=func.now())
        departments = relationship(
        Department,
        secondary='department_employee_link'
    )


class DepartmentEmployeeLink(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department_employee_link'
    department_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('department.id'), primary_key=True)
    employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Would the existing foreign key many-to-one relationship allow a similar approach, if the missing `relationship` were provided?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you're expecting Alice to have a department of 1.  Nothing is setting the department id, so it gets persisted as null.

You need to pass a department id if you want alice to have a deparmtent id.

something like

e = Employee(employee_name='alice', department_id=1)

instead of

e = Employee(employee_name='alice')