# Referencing non-committed primary key in one session in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

Is it possible to add an object to a session in SQLAlchemy and reference its PK in that same session?

I have a class table in my DB (with a unique id) and after creating a new class I want to add students (every student has a FK referencing the class id) to the class.
It's absolutely possible that I'm doing something wrong but I'm getting an error saying that the referenced PK is not present in the table, so I have to commit the session every time I create a new class.

Is there any way to solve this ploblem?

Comment: Sounds like you might be after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242523/get-inserted-key-before-commit-session, but you can also let the ORM handle key handling, if you have defined `relationship` attributes that connect the models in question. All in all, please provide a [mcve] when asking debugging questions.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for :)